# How use QML Drawer with Qt Widgets?

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I would like to know how could I make the QApplication UI the root window of a QML Drawer item on a PyQt5 project.

In principle, I am capable of making them work together but the Drawer keeps displaying on a different window instead of applying the same effect to the root window.

Just as an example, I was trying to include the functionality of the "[Qt Quick Controls 2 - Gallery](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.11/qtquickcontrols2-gallery-example.html)" onto the project.

Check the following code for further details:

```
# mainwindow.py

class MainWindow:

   def __init__(self):
      self.qtApplication = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
      qtPbObj = QtWidgets.QPushButton
      QtWidgets.QPushButton = hoverButton

      self.mw = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
      self.mw.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | self.mw.windowFlags())
      self.qtMainWindowUi = main_ui.Ui_MainWindow()
      self.qtMainWindowUi.setupUi(self.mw)
      QtWidgets.QPushButton = qtPbObj

       ...

      engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

      context = engine.rootContext()
      file = os.path.join(DIR_PATH, "main.qml")
      url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(file)    
      engine.load(url)

      engine.setParent(self.qtApplication.instance())

      if not engine.rootObjects():
         logger.error("No object could be loaded from sourced QML file")
         self.qtApplication.exit(-1)

      rootWindow = engine.rootObjects()[0]
```

The QML file used can be found [here](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.11/qtquickcontrols2-gallery-gallery-qml.html).

---

Update:

In the project, while keeping the **setupUi** and **frameless** features implemented, I would like to have the QML Drawer functionality only available when clicking the "≡", so that it overlaps the MainWindow central_widget:

Attached some captures to explain better the actual status:

**Actual UI:**

[image]

[image]

**Ideal solution:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the concepts, the root of the QWidget is not a QApplication but it is a necessary requirement. In your case you must embed the QML application in a QWidget, and for this there are several alternatives as indicated in this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59804240/6622587) but in this case I will show the solution using QQuickView.

For the above, the following must be modified:

- As QQuickView is to be used, ApplicationWindow should not be used, but the root must be an Item and redistribute the ToolBar, StackView and Drawer so that the GUI structure is maintained..
- As I will not use .qrc, you must modify the paths placed in the model of "qrc:/pages /..." to "pages/...".
- The QQuickStyle class is not accessible from PyQt so the solutions to establish the style and icons will have to be implemented alternately.

Considering the above, the code is as follows:

**main.py**

```py
import os
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtQuick, QtWidgets

DIR_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
ICON_DIR = os.path.join(DIR_PATH, "icons")


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(central_widget)

        lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("QLabel", alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter))

        file = os.path.join(DIR_PATH, "gallery.qml")
        self.view = QtQuick.QQuickView()
        self.view.statusChanged.connect(self.on_statusChanged)
        self.view.setResizeMode(QtQuick.QQuickView.SizeRootObjectToView)
        engine = self.view.engine()
        context = engine.rootContext()
        context.setContextProperty("availableStyles", availableStyles())
        self.view.setSource(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(file))
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget.createWindowContainer(self.view)
        lay.addWidget(widget)

    def on_statusChanged(self, status):
        if status == QtQuick.QQuickView.Error:
            for error in self.view.errors():
                print(error.toString())
            sys.exit(-1)


def availableStyles():
    # https://github.com/qt/qtquickcontrols2/blob/5.14/src/quickcontrols2/qquickstyle.cpp#L591

    importPaths = [
        QtCore.QLibraryInfo.location(QtCore.QLibraryInfo.Qml2ImportsPath),
        ":/qt-project.org/imports",
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.applicationDirPath(),
        DIR_PATH,
    ]
    path = os.environ.get("QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_STYLE_PATH", "")
    if path:
        importPaths.append(path)

    stylePaths = []
    targetPath = "QtQuick/Controls.2"
    for importPath in importPaths:
        d = QtCore.QDir(importPath)
        if d.cd(targetPath):
            stylePaths.append(d.absolutePath())

    styles = []
    for path in stylePaths:
        entries = QtCore.QDir(path).entryInfoList(
            QtCore.QDir.Dirs | QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot
        )
        for entry in entries:
            name = entry.fileName()
            if not name.endswith(".dSYM") and name != "designer":
                # print(path, name)
                styles.append(name)
    return list(set(styles))


def main():

    QtCore.QCoreApplication.setApplicationName("Gallery")
    QtCore.QCoreApplication.setOrganizationName("QtProject")
    QtCore.QCoreApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    QtGui.QIcon.setThemeSearchPaths(QtGui.QIcon.themeSearchPaths() + [ICON_DIR])
    QtGui.QIcon.setThemeName("gallery")

    default_style = "Material"

    settings = QtCore.QSettings()
    style = settings.value("style")
    if not style:
        style = default_style
        settings.setValue("style", style)

    os.environ["QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_STYLE"] = style

    w = MainWindow()
    w.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**gallery.qml**

```
/****************************************************************************
**
** Copyright (C) 2017 The Qt Company Ltd.
** Contact: https://www.qt.io/licensing/
**
** This file is part of the examples of the Qt Toolkit.
**
** $QT_BEGIN_LICENSE:BSD$
** Commercial License Usage
** Licensees holding valid commercial Qt licenses may use this file in
** accordance with the commercial license agreement provided with the
** Software or, alternatively, in accordance with the terms contained in
** a written agreement between you and The Qt Company. For licensing terms
** and conditions see https://www.qt.io/terms-conditions. For further
** information use the contact form at https://www.qt.io/contact-us.
**
** BSD License Usage
** Alternatively, you may use this file under the terms of the BSD license
** as follows:
**
** "Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
** modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
** met:
**   * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
**     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
**   * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
**     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
**     the documentation and/or other materials provided with the
**     distribution.
**   * Neither the name of The Qt Company Ltd nor the names of its
**     contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
**     from this software without specific prior written permission.
**
**
** THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
** "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
** LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
** A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
** OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
** SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
** LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
** DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
** THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
** (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
** OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE."
**
** $QT_END_LICENSE$
**
****************************************************************************/

import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls.Universal 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.14
import Qt.labs.settings 1.0

Item {
    id: window
    width: 360
    height: 520
    visible: true
    //title: "Qt Quick Controls 2"

    Settings {
        id: settings
        property string style: "Default"
    }

    Shortcut {
        sequences: ["Esc", "Back"]
        enabled: stackView.depth > 1
        onActivated: navigateBackAction.trigger()
    }

    Action {
        id: navigateBackAction
        icon.name: stackView.depth > 1 ? "back" : "drawer"
        onTriggered: {
            if (stackView.depth > 1) {
                stackView.pop()
                listView.currentIndex = -1
            } else {
                drawer.open()
            }
        }
    }

    Shortcut {
        sequence: "Menu"
        onActivated: optionsMenuAction.trigger()
    }

    Action {
        id: optionsMenuAction
        icon.name: "menu"
        onTriggered: optionsMenu.open()
    }

    Drawer {
        id: drawer
        width: Math.min(window.width, window.height) / 3 * 2
        height: window.height
        interactive: stackView.depth === 1

        ListView {
            id: listView

            focus: true
            currentIndex: -1
            anchors.fill: parent

            delegate: ItemDelegate {
                width: parent.width
                text: model.title
                highlighted: ListView.isCurrentItem
                onClicked: {
                    listView.currentIndex = index
                    stackView.push(model.source)
                    drawer.close()
                }
            }

            model: ListModel {
                ListElement { title: "BusyIndicator"; source: "pages/BusyIndicatorPage.qml" }
                ListElement { title: "Button"; source: "pages/ButtonPage.qml" }
                ListElement { title: "CheckBox"; source: "pages/CheckBoxPage.qml" }
                ListElement { title: "ComboBox"; source: "pages/ComboBoxPage.qml" }
                ListElement { title: "DelayButton"; source: "pages/DelayButtonPage.qml" }
                ListElement { title: "Dial"; source: "pages/DialPage.qml" }
                ListElement { title: "Dialog"; source: "pages/DialogPage.qml" }
                ListElement { title: "Delegates"; source: "pages/DelegatePage.qml" }
                ListElement { title: "Frame"; source: "pages/FramePage.qml" }
                ListElement { title: "GroupBox"; source: "pages/GroupBoxPage.qml" }
                ListElement { title: "PageIndicator"; source: "pages/PageIndicatorPage.qml" }
                ListElement { title: "ProgressBar"; source: "pages/ProgressBarPage.qml" }
                ListElement { title: "RadioButton"; source: "pages/RadioButtonPage.qml" }
                ListElement { title: "RangeSlider"; source: "pages/RangeSliderPage.qml" }
                ListElement { title: "ScrollBar"; source: "pages/ScrollBarPage.qml" }
                ListElement { title: "ScrollIndicator"; source: "pages/ScrollIndicatorPage.qml" }
                ListElement { title: "Slider"; source: "pages/SliderPage.qml" }
                ListElement { title: "SpinBox"; source: "pages/SpinBoxPage.qml" }
                ListElement { title: "StackView"; source: "pages/StackViewPage.qml" }
                ListElement { title: "SwipeView"; source: "pages/SwipeViewPage.qml" }
                ListElement { title: "Switch"; source: "pages/SwitchPage.qml" }
                ListElement { title: "TabBar"; source: "pages/TabBarPage.qml" }
                ListElement { title: "TextArea"; source: "pages/TextAreaPage.qml" }
                ListElement { title: "TextField"; source: "pages/TextFieldPage.qml" }
                ListElement { title: "ToolTip"; source: "pages/ToolTipPage.qml" }
                ListElement { title: "Tumbler"; source: "pages/TumblerPage.qml" }
            }

            ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator { }
        }
    }

    ColumnLayout{
        anchors.fill: parent
        ToolBar {
            Material.foreground: "white"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            RowLayout {
                spacing: 20
                anchors.fill: parent

                ToolButton {
                    action: navigateBackAction
                }

                Label {
                    id: titleLabel
                    text: listView.currentItem ? listView.currentItem.text : "Gallery"
                    font.pixelSize: 20
                    elide: Label.ElideRight
                    horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                    verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                }

                ToolButton {
                    action: optionsMenuAction

                    Menu {
                        id: optionsMenu
                        x: parent.width - width
                        transformOrigin: Menu.TopRight

                        Action {
                            text: "Settings"
                            onTriggered: settingsDialog.open()
                        }
                        Action {
                            text: "About"
                            onTriggered: aboutDialog.open()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        StackView {
            id: stackView
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true

            initialItem: Pane {
                id: pane

                Image {
                    id: logo
                    width: pane.availableWidth / 2
                    height: pane.availableHeight / 2
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    anchors.verticalCenterOffset: -50
                    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                    source: "images/qt-logo.png"
                }

                Label {
                    text: "Qt Quick Controls 2 provides a set of controls that can be used to build complete interfaces in Qt Quick."
                    anchors.margins: 20
                    anchors.top: logo.bottom
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    anchors.bottom: arrow.top
                    horizontalAlignment: Label.AlignHCenter
                    verticalAlignment: Label.AlignVCenter
                    wrapMode: Label.Wrap
                }

                Image {
                    id: arrow
                    source: "images/arrow.png"
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                }
            }
        }

        Dialog {
            id: settingsDialog
            x: Math.round((window.width - width) / 2)
            y: Math.round(window.height / 6)
            width: Math.round(Math.min(window.width, window.height) / 3 * 2)
            modal: true
            focus: true
            title: "Settings"

            standardButtons: Dialog.Ok | Dialog.Cancel
            onAccepted: {
                settings.style = styleBox.displayText
                settingsDialog.close()
            }
            onRejected: {
                styleBox.currentIndex = styleBox.styleIndex
                settingsDialog.close()
            }

            contentItem: ColumnLayout {
                id: settingsColumn
                spacing: 20

                RowLayout {
                    spacing: 10

                    Label {
                        text: "Style:"
                    }

                    ComboBox {
                        id: styleBox
                        property int styleIndex: -1
                        model: availableStyles
                        Component.onCompleted: {
                            styleIndex = find(settings.style, Qt.MatchFixedString)
                            if (styleIndex !== -1)
                                currentIndex = styleIndex
                        }
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                    }
                }

                Label {
                    text: "Restart required"
                    color: "#e41e25"
                    opacity: styleBox.currentIndex !== styleBox.styleIndex ? 1.0 : 0.0
                    horizontalAlignment: Label.AlignHCenter
                    verticalAlignment: Label.AlignVCenter
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                }
            }
        }

        Dialog {
            id: aboutDialog
            modal: true
            focus: true
            title: "About"
            x: (window.width - width) / 2
            y: window.height / 6
            width: Math.min(window.width, window.height) / 3 * 2
            contentHeight: aboutColumn.height

            Column {
                id: aboutColumn
                spacing: 20

                Label {
                    width: aboutDialog.availableWidth
                    text: "The Qt Quick Controls 2 module delivers the next generation user interface controls based on Qt Quick."
                    wrapMode: Label.Wrap
                    font.pixelSize: 12
                }

                Label {
                    width: aboutDialog.availableWidth
                    text: "In comparison to the desktop-oriented Qt Quick Controls 1, Qt Quick Controls 2 "
                          + "are an order of magnitude simpler, lighter and faster, and are primarily targeted "
                          + "towards embedded and mobile platforms."
                    wrapMode: Label.Wrap
                    font.pixelSize: 12
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
├── gallery.qml
├── icons
│   └── gallery
│       ├── 20x20
│       │   ├── back.png
│       │   ├── drawer.png
│       │   └── menu.png
│       ├── 20x20@2
│       │   ├── back.png
│       │   ├── drawer.png
│       │   └── menu.png
│       ├── 20x20@3
│       │   ├── back.png
│       │   ├── drawer.png
│       │   └── menu.png
│       ├── 20x20@4
│       │   ├── back.png
│       │   ├── drawer.png
│       │   └── menu.png
│       └── index.theme
├── images
│   ├── arrow@2x.png
│   ├── arrow@3x.png
│   ├── arrow@4x.png
│   ├── arrow.png
│   ├── arrows@2x.png
│   ├── arrows@3x.png
│   ├── arrows@4x.png
│   ├── arrows.png
│   ├── qt-logo@2x.png
│   ├── qt-logo@3x.png
│   ├── qt-logo@4x.png
│   └── qt-logo.png
├── main.py
└── pages
    ├── BusyIndicatorPage.qml
    ├── ButtonPage.qml
    ├── CheckBoxPage.qml
    ├── ComboBoxPage.qml
    ├── DelayButtonPage.qml
    ├── DelegatePage.qml
    ├── DialogPage.qml
    ├── DialPage.qml
    ├── FramePage.qml
    ├── GroupBoxPage.qml
    ├── PageIndicatorPage.qml
    ├── ProgressBarPage.qml
    ├── RadioButtonPage.qml
    ├── RangeSliderPage.qml
    ├── ScrollablePage.qml
    ├── ScrollBarPage.qml
    ├── ScrollIndicatorPage.qml
    ├── SliderPage.qml
    ├── SpinBoxPage.qml
    ├── StackViewPage.qml
    ├── SwipeViewPage.qml
    ├── SwitchPage.qml
    ├── TabBarPage.qml
    ├── TextAreaPage.qml
    ├── TextFieldPage.qml
    ├── ToolTipPage.qml
    └── TumblerPage.qml
```

[image]

<sub>The full example can be found [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/59828470)</sub>